# A question on limitsup

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, limsup-and-liminf

What is the relationship between $\lim \sup _{n}\left(a_{n} b_{n}\right)$ and  $(\lim \sup _{n} a_{n})(\lim \sup _{n} b_{n})$?

Comment: If we use $a_n : 1,0,1,0,1,0,\ldots$ and $b_n: 0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1, \ldots$, $a_n b_n \equiv 0$ and so  $\limsup a_n b_n =0 $  while $\limsup_n a_n = 1 = \limsup_n b_n$..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_n$, $b_n$ are negative, just consider instead $-a_n$, $-b_n$, so that they are $\geq 0$. As you can find, for instance, on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior), it can be shown that:
$$ \limsup_{n \rightarrow + \infty} (a_n b_n) \leq (\limsup_{n \rightarrow + \infty} a_n) \cdot  (\limsup_{n \rightarrow + \infty} b_n) $$
while
$$  \liminf_{n \rightarrow + \infty} (a_n b_n) \geq  (\liminf_{n \rightarrow + \infty} a_n) \cdot (\liminf_{n \rightarrow + \infty} b_n)$$
(where we are assuming that no indeterminate forms arise from the products of the limits).
You can prove these inequalities using some simple properties of $\sup$ and $\inf$ and the definitions of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$.